# How you format date time like "2012-12-11 12:00:00"

Tags: python, datetime

now I have datetime like mintt

```
In [134]: mintt
Out[134]: datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 9, 23, 21, 10, 548382, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x2f805d0>)
```

and I change it like this:

```
In [131]: mintt.isoformat(" ").split(".")[0]
Out[131]: '2012-05-09 23:21:10'
```

how can I delete the minute and seconds,let it become "2012-05-09 23:00:00" ?

PS:at the beginning I use method below:

```
In [135]: mintt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
Out[135]: '2012-05-09 23:00:00'
```

but it will raise an exception like' year=1601 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900'

so I use isoformat method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `datetime.replace()` method.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t = datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 9, 23, 21, 10, 548382)
>>> t.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0).isoformat(' ')
'2012-05-09 23:00:00'
```

This doesn't change `t`, it creates a new object.

```
>>> t
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 9, 23, 21, 10, 548382) # still has same value
```

Comment: may be since the version reason,I get what I want by below codes:In [145]: mintt.replace(minute=0,second=0).isoformat(' ').split(".")[0]Out[145]: '2012-05-09 23:00:00' thank you for helping me solve the basic problem:)

Comment: @orokusaki: Reread [PEP-8 naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).

Comment: @DietrichEpp - pardon me, I meant "Pylint", which doesn't really matter in the context of an SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could subtract the seconds and minutes from your original time...

```
nominsec = mintt - datetime.timedelta(minutes=mintt.minute, seconds=mintt.second)
```

Comment: to be honest, I like Dietrich's solution better

Answer (score 0):

If its a `datetime` object, maybe this?:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012-05-09 23:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 9, 23, 0)
>>> "{} {}:00:00".format(dt.date(),dt.hour)
'2012-05-09 23:00:00'
```